# Make extension compatible for TYPO3 v8

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I have a problem in TYPO3 v8.5.0 dev with own extensions.
After creating a proper composer.json my classes are not found. Installation was done by copy into the typo3conf/ext folder as usual and activating in extension manager. Unfortunally the ext is not in TER, so this is the only way.
After activating, i'm stuck with error:

> Oops, an error occurred!
>
> Class 'XXX\ExtKey...' not found

What do I miss so my classes are found again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your extension is not installed with composer you have to add the autoload settings into the composer.json of the project.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Test\\Yourext\\": "web/typo3conf/ext/yourext/Classes"
    }
  }
```

Then you have to do a **composer update** or **composer dump-autoload**

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what i missed. Works!