# Own TYPO3 Extension with composer: Could not analyse class maybe not loaded or no autoloader?

Tags: composer-php, typo3, typo3-extensions

I just wrote my first TYPO3 Extension, but it doesn't work :( 
I got this error message at my TYPO3 Frontend:

> Could not analyse class:
>   "Snowboard\SnowboardStaff\Controller\SnowboardTeacherController" maybe
>   not loaded or no autoloader? Class
>   Snowboard\SnowboardStaff\Controller\SnowboardTeacherController does
>   not exist

I installed TYPO3 with composer. So may be this problem have something to do with this?

I already tried al lot, so please help me :)

Comment: I don't know much about TYPO3, but maybe you need to manually add it to your autoloader in `composer.json`

Comment: Is your extension a composer package on it‘s own (i.e. a requirement in your root `composer.json`) or is it part of your site package?

Comment: The extension is a part of my site package. It is under /typo3conf/ext/snowboard_staff

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make extension compatible for TYPO3 v8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41111195/make-extension-compatible-for-typo3-v8)

Answer (score 6):

If you installed your extension with composer you can place the `autoload` in the extension's `composer.json` file like "Thomas" already wrote. But if you just put your extension into the `typo3cond/ext` folder you **must** add the `autoload` settings in the main `composer.json` file in your root directory.

composer.json in the extension:

```
"autoload": {
   "psr-4": {
      "Vendor\\Yourext\\": "Classes/"
   }
},
```

composer.json in root:

```
"autoload": {
   "psr-4": {
      "Vendor\\Yourext\\": "web/typo3conf/ext/startpilot/Classes"
   }
 },
```

Comment: This is correct. Further information can be found here: https://usetypo3.com/typo3-and-composer.html

Comment: This is a very good explanation. I love it! But the point of "Run code snippet" escapes me for this kind of snippet. As does "Copy snippet to answer". Maybe you can explain this or just make a plain snippet out of it? (copy snippet to clipboard might be useful)

Comment: SybillePeters thx for the hint - just updated the code format

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the location of your classes into your extension's composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "Snowboard\\SnowboardStaff\\": "Classes/",
  }
}
```